# Will an API call over HTTP be secure if it is made after some kind of authentication?

Tags: jquery, security, http, https

I'm making a couple of API calls using JQuery. The first call is for authentication and I receive a token that can be used for the next call. This first call is made over HTTPS but would like to make the second call over HTTP. Will this second call over HTTP be secure since I'm already authenticated?

BTW the response will still be returned over HTTPS.

Comment: _"BTW the response will still be returned over HTTPS."_ No it won't. Request and response must match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the request and response can be intercepted, and also changed by other parties. This is particularly easy over wifi (see [FireSheep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep))

Just bear down and use HTTPS, it's free and fast and easy these days.